# How to get row count (from other table) using subquery in propel?

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT a.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b where b.col1 = a.col2) as count FROM a
```

is it possible using propel criteria or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addSelectColumn(aPeer::TABLE_NAME.'.*');
$c->addAsColumn('count', '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b WHERE b.col1 = a.col2)');
aPeer::doSelect($c);
```